# turn off auto-creating index paths from embedded documents in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Seems like mongoose is auto generating indexes for embedded documents.

Is there an option to turn off the auto-magical indexes that are created? For example the code https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L940 seems to collectIndexes from any subdocuments.

Am I missing something or is there a way to disable this and be explicit about which subdocuments need indexing? We require this, because we are hitting the limit of 64 total indexes per collection limit, which is enforced by MongoDB.

Comment: The only indexes that Mongoose creates are based on indexing options that you explicitly define in the schema -- nothing's automatic.  Can you update your question to contain your schema where you're seeing this?

Comment: If you define indexes on a schema that you embed in another schema, it will automatically create indexes on the parent collection referencing the subdocument paths. For now, I've got a workaround of simply overriding `schema.indexes()` to just return `schema._indexes` and it works as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging through source code, I don't see anyway of adding an option. My workaround is this:

```
schema.indexes = function () {
    return schema._indexes;
};
```